# Resize background img removing padding

Tags: html, css

I have a background img inside a div, and when I try to scale this image, there is a padding (I suppose) that it prevents me from placing items on the right side:

[image]

The padding is the green color that is out of the image. I want to fit this padding to my img.

This is my Sass code:

```
%types {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: left top;
   padding-top: 130px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   background-size: 300px auto;
}
.type1 {
   @extend %types;
   background-image: url("img/events/templates/tpl1.png");
}
...
```

And here is my HTML code (with Foundation):

```
<div class="small-10 columns">
   <div class="type1"></div>
   ... (more content I want to the right of the div)
</div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Can you post your code in JSFiddle please.